# Address Book App adds the letter "n" to my notes

Tags: macos, contacts

The Address Book app adds the letter "n" to notes of contacts in most of my contacts. In the Notes field I randomly see the letter added in front of names, numbers etc.

I have off course tried to delete the letter, but after a sync the letters are back. I see both 1, 2 and 3 repeats of the same letter in my notes.

What to do?

Comment: I assume that Address book is on the Mac. When you sync, what are you syncing to? And, what does your address book/contacts look like on the other device or iCloud?

Comment: Yes, on mac (Lion, latest updates) syncing to both iPad/iPhone and MBP and here everything looks fine. I only get the extra "n" in Address Book on the iMac

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug with iCloud. I started seeing the same behavior when I started using iCloud. When I turned iCloud off and went back to syncing over the cable, the issue of extra "n"s went away.

Try backing up your address book (just in case) and turning off iCloud for a while. If that fixes it, you can make the choice on if you would rather have it on and deal with the "n"s or off and have to sync with the cable.

*Of course, this will also likely get fixed in future release as iCloud is tweaked*